# Set Java 1.6 default over 1.7 in Ubuntu Linux

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, version

Here is the output to some inspection that I did:

```
$ java -version

java version "1.7.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_21-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.21-b01, mixed mode)
```

and

```
$ update-java-alternatives -l

java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64 1061 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64
```

and

```
$ ls /usr/lib/jvm/

default-java  java-1.5.0-gcj-4.6  java-1.6.0-openjdk  java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64  java-6-openjdk  java-6-openjdk-amd64  java-6-openjdk-common  java-7-openjdk-amd64
```

With that in mind, how do I go about changing the default to 1.6 so that when I execute java -version, it tells me 1.6?

Thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I am on Fedora but I hope that alternatives works the same way on Ubuntu. You need to run `update-alternatives --config java` (on Fedora just `alternatives --config java`) to see what options you have. Then type the number of the JDK you want to use and press enter. And that's it:-)

Comment: We don't seem to have that package.  There's a galternatives and an update-alternatives....

Comment: Whoa!  update-alternatives did exactly what you suggested!  That's awesome.  I was expecting an uninstall/reinstall or some such process.  That was easy.  Thanks!

Comment: I was about to write it about after bit of googling:-)you are welcome

Comment: @MrA Somehow, even after I use that command, the default-java is still pointing to the old version. I am trying to update from 7 to 8, installed openjdk-8-jdk and then ran `update-java-alternatives`. Seeing java-1.7.0 was still what default-java was pointing at, I tried your command, but it remained the same. Any idea as to why this is happening?

Comment: Did you try it with `sudo`?

Answer (score 1):

us below command to set the java. 
sudo update-alternatives --config java

It will display the option to select you appropriate java version

Answer (score 0):

Set default java:

```
mv /usr/bin/java /usr/bin/java_1.6

ln -s /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_55/bin/java /usr/bin/
```

Comment: First we need to check the version on using java -version .
if it is java_1.6 version please run above commands.